Use Discord's desktop app to search a Forum Channel for my posts
How can I use Discord's desktop Windows app to search a Forum channel for my posts?
I can normally search a channel by entering from:<myusername> in the channel search bar but the same search returns nothing when applied to a forum channel.


You need to combine both in: and from: filters, in the regular (not forum) search bar. Type the channel name after in: and username after from:.


If you want to search only your threads, it's unfortunately currently not a feature. The only workaround I can think of would be writing a bot that takes input like /searchforum [username], then compares it against all messages in forum type of channels (GUILD_FORUM). The comparison would check the author.username and type fields to only limit to thread starting messages. This of course would only be freely available in your own servers.

Dedicated Search Bar
You can search a forum channel for your posts using from:myUserId in the channel's dedicated search bar located to the right of the "Notifications Settings" & "Show/Hide Member List" buttons: 

Resources:

Forum Channels FAQ
How To Search For A Forum Post

